# First School App

Tags: android

I have to program my first app in school and here is my code:

I have problems at the `setOnClickListener` part. It doesn't work, can you please help me and tell me my mistakes?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView input, output;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        input = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Eingabefeld);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View view) {

            boolean Check() {

                if (isNumber(input.getText().charAt(0)) == true) {
                    output.setText("This is a Number");
                }
                else {
                    if (isLetter(input.getText().charAt(0)) == true) {
                        output.setText("This is a Letter");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        output.setText("This is a Gigit");
                    }
                }
            return true;
            }
        }
    });


    }
    public boolean isNumber(char myChar) {
        if ((int)myChar >= 48 && (int)myChar <= 57) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isLetter(char myChar) {
        if ((int)myChar >=97 && (int)myChar <=122) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isDigit(char myChar) {
        if ((int)myChar >=33 && (int)myChar <=47) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: _It doesn't work, can you please help me and tell me my mistakes_ This is not a problem statement. Please take the Tour and read the Help Center.

Comment: @Ani Are you getting any error?

Comment: Help us help you. `It doesn't work` tells us absolutely nothing about the problem. Compile error(s)? Runtime exception(s)? Unexpected functionality? Something else? Be as detailed as possible if you want any help.

Comment: With a cursory glance, it appears you are trying to define a Check() method *inside* another method onClick().  But you need to describe your problem(s) better.

Comment: When I Click on the Button it should identify my input in the TextView and tell me if it is a Number, Letter and a Digit. And it shows an error at the public void onClick() part and I don't understand why?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a boolean Check function inside your click handler?

I think what you meant to do was:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
            if (isNumber(input.getText().charAt(0)) == true) {
                output.setText("This is a Number");
            }
            else {
                if (isLetter(input.getText().charAt(0)) == true) {
                    output.setText("This is a Letter");
                }
                else
                {
                    output.setText("This is a Gigit");
                }
            }

    }
});
```

Comment: I agree, it makes no sense to have one there.